# How to set formula value in openpyxl

Tags: python, export-to-excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a simple tool to work on .csv and .xlsx files. The idea is to read in data as .csv add some modifications and export to .xlsx with the modifications added. I've got everything working but when I try to write out to the .xlsx file (using openpyxl in Python) I'm having some trouble. When I open the document in either LibreOffice Calc or Gnumeric some fields aren't showing. The fields I'm having trouble with include formulas. When I click on them the formulas are correctly typed in the field, but nothing is shown in the field. If I retype a character in the formula it's evaluated and the value shows up.

I had a poke around in the underlying .xml of the worksheet and the cells obviously doesn't have a cache. But I also noticed that it didn't always have the right data type. I tried to fix this by explicitly setting the type to formula but no luck.

What I use now to set the cell is:

```
cell = ws.cell(column=i,row=j)
cell.set_explicit_value(value=val,data_type=cell.TYPE_FORMULA)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a formula that is not being correctly interpreted?

openpyxl itself never evaluates formulae (this is out of scope) so there is never a cached value.

Comment: =A1*B1, it's everything. But I've figured out that the issue is with both libreoffice and gnumeric. I tried opening it in excel at it worked. So it seems like it's the readers not handling missing a cache. However they seem to be able to do things like =A1*2, at least in some cases. So it might be that it's just chaining, e.g. C1=A1*2, B1=C1*D1, then B1 wouldn't calculate. What I would like to see is a way to set the cached value, and then let it be up to the programmer to set the correct value.

Comment: We have no intentions to add support for cached values as well as formulae as this would considerably complicate the library.

Comment: Not really. I'm not saying that the cached values should be verified. I'm just saying that there should be an option to add them, then it'd be up to the programmer to ensure that they are correct. In my case this would be really easy since the only reason why I add formulas to my sheet is so that I can change variables in the sheet later. But if your case is more complicated the programmer could opt for a separate engine to evaluate the formulaes. This would also allow spreadsheets to load faster, which is the reasoning behind cache values.

Comment: Your case may be simple but openpyxl supports reading and writing. Reading a cell which may or may not have a formula and associated cached value is not straightforward. xlsxwriter, which only writes files does allow you to set a cached value, though it also tells the reading application to recalculate.

LibreOffice should recalculate all the cells, so it sounds like you've hit a bug. Never worked with Gnumeric so I can't comment on it. There are definitely some "viewer" apps out there that try and get away without a formula engine.

Comment: From looking at the XML it seems to not be much of a problem to have functions for reading in both the formula itself and the cached value separately. It's weird, when I open the formula in LibreOffice and erase something and then rewrite it the calculations runs. But not until then. Gnumeric is the standard reader/writer application for spreadsheets in Xubuntu (possibly also regular Ubuntu). I've had no issues with it besides files generated from openpyxl..

Comment: We support either/or when reading files. But that's why *don't* support generating cached values.

Feel free to submit a bug with a file that you think should be recalculating but isn't.